# Dragable UIImageView is Teleporting when tapping somewhere else

Tags: ios, uiimageview

The code below is based on the idea of how to make a UIImageView be able to be dragged around the ViewController. When I use this code however, I click on a different location instead of pressing on the Image and it teleports to that location instead of requiring me to always drag the image. I want the code below to only work when pressing on that specific image. Please Help-

```
-(void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];

    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:touch.view];

    image.center = location;

    [self ifCollided];
}

-(void) touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    [self touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}
```

Comment: Why not use a pan gesture recognizer attached to the image view instead?  Its action method will only be called if the original touch is over the image view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's teleporting simply because you don't have any check for whether the user has in fact touched the image, so any touch causes the image to jump to that location. What you need to do is check if the user has touched the image, then move it only if they have. Try the following code in the ViewController, assuming 'image' is the draggable view:

You'll need to create a variable/property on your ViewController to track if the view is being dragged. If you need just one image, you can use a `BOOL` (the code below assumes you've done this, called `isDragging`).

```
-(void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:image];
    if([image pointInside:location withEvent:event]) {
        isDragging = YES;
    }
}

-(void) touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [super touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];
    if(isDragging)
    {
        UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
        CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:self.view];
        image.center = location;
        [self ifCollided];
    }
}

-(void) touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [super touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
    isDragging = NO;
}
```

This code basically does a check in `touchesBegan` and sets the property to true if you touch inside the image, moves it in `touchesMoved` if your initial touch was on the image, and finally unsets the check in `touchesEnded`.

Comment: Glad to be of help :) Remember to accept an answer if it resolves your issue.